# Remapping Alt+` to ESC

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

My <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is broken on my keyboard, and I would like to remap it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (that's <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>`</kbd> grave accent, same button as the <kbd>~</kbd> tilde). However:

```
!`::Esc
```

will trigger <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> when pressed (!<kbd>Esc</kbd>) because the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is held down. How do I remap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> so that, when pressed, it will trigger <kbd>Esc</kbd> rather than <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>?

EDIT: I am not opposed to using an entirely different program to remap my keys. I just want to remap <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to
the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in all of my Windows.

Comment: Not sure about your specific problem, but in case you don't find a solution: please see https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remarks , it says "When a script is launched, each remapping is translated into a pair of hotkeys ..." You could copy that piece of code and adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SendPlay](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm):

```
!`::sendplay {Esc}
```

> SendPlay [...] buffers any physical keyboard or mouse activity during the send, which prevents the user's keystrokes from being interspersed with those being sent.

Comment: Works on AHK 1.1.21.03 & Windows7.

Answer (score 1):

I found two possible ways to achieve this.

---

Use [BlockInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/BlockInput.htm)

> Disables or enables the user's ability to interact with the computer via keyboard and mouse.

```
!p::
    BlockInput On
    send {Esc}
    BlockInput, Off
return
```

You might need to run the script as administrator and the alt and/or p may get stuck down, which led me to the second solution.

---

Use [KeyWait](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm)

> Waits for a key or mouse/joystick button to be released or pressed down.

```
!p::
    KeyWait, Alt
    send {Esc}
return
```

Comment: Thanks, I get back home later this week so I'll test it then.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
!`::
    SendInput, {Alt Up}{Esc}
Return
```